# Visual studio 2012 - silverlight - XAML designer - Insert grid row before/ after

Tags: visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0, xaml-designer

Just switched to visual studio 2012, and I can't figure out how to insert a new row into a silverlight grid through the xaml designer.

In visual studio 2010, we could easily insert rows and columns into our silverlight grid just by *left clicking > rows > insert before*. When we did this it would automatically re-number all the rest of the controls' row numbers.

I don't want to have to re-number every control by hand, has this super convenient feature been removed from 2012? Or is there some new way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found the answer here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightdevtools/thread/0dc73921-c1bd-465e-b584-c14d7863fa73

"I found the insert row/column.   The new UI style in 2012 makes it harder to see drop downs.  If you hover over the left or top edge of the grid, a tiny dropdown arrow will popup with the options moved to there instead of right clicking as cell as it was in 2010.

Also you can now move stuff around from Document outline so I only really need behavior support in 2012 so I can ditch Blend."

Answer (score 0):

What grid is that?, I know:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="68*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="96*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="136*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

With this grid I don't insert rows by left clicking in neither VS

Comment: Yes, it works with this grid. But the UI in Visual Studio 2012 is very bad here - it took me a while to find it as well. You need to hover the small edge of a row or a column. Then a small white tooltip appears with a little dropdown arrow to the right. Here you can choose "Add row before/after"...