# How to Add row without changing all Column/Row id

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I've a huge grid in wpf (xaml)

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="400">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    ...
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<Label>1</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

<Label Grid.Row="1">1</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>

<Label Grid.Row="2">2</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>

...
...
...
```

I would like to add a row at the top of my grid. For now, I change **Grid.Row="1"** by **Grid.Row="2"** and **Grid.Row="2"** by **Grid.Row="3"** ... It's really painful !

Is there any solution to add rows without changing all ID ?

Comment: I am keenly looking for answer to this, every time I have to deal with something like this .. I get requirements changed ..!

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127688/visual-studio-2012-silverlight-xaml-designer-insert-grid-row-before-after)'s an answer for 2012.

Comment: @MártonMolnár Yeah ! That works, thanks ! (so hard to find)

Comment: @dkozl Cause I'm a newbie and it's the simplest solution I found, but why not